# Capacitor Google Maps Android issue

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am working on a project to add Google Maps inside a mobile app.
For this project i use Ionic React and `@capacitor/google-maps` library.
On Ios it displays just find but on Android i keep getting a blank screen.

This is the problem:
I know that on Android the Maps appears behind the webview. The documentation suggest that i use `ion-content background: none; or transparant;`. The problem is that i am showing the maps inside a modal. Making the background transparent is not a option for me. This results to a transparent modal.

Is there a way to display the Google Maps inside a Modal?